# How to apply 'where' filter to a transformed column in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, where-clause

I have a column `event_title` with values:

| event_title |
| --- |
| 2/24/2022 - event foo |
| 2/25/2022 - event bar |
| event baz |

I want to parse the date strings as a date, and filter out records where no date string is present.

My query is:

```
SELECT
    event_title,
    PARSE_DATE('%D', REGEXP_EXTRACT(event_title,r'\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,4}')) AS event_date
FROM my_table
WHERE event_date is not null;
```

with expected output being:

| event_title | event_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2/24/2022 - event foo | 2/24/2022 |
| 2/25/2022 - event bar | 2/25/2022 |

I get an error saying `Unrecognized name: "event_date"`

Seems like it should be possible to filter by a transformed column with an alias, am I mistaken? Any suggestions on best practices for implementing this query?

Comment: This is an order of operation issue.  SQL is processed FROM WHERE then select.  so event_date isn't known in the where clause as teh select hasn't built it yet. Either wrap select in an outer select and then you can use it, or use a CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by Mikhail above explains perfectly. You could also use your own column as a filter as well :

```
SELECT
  event_title,
  PARSE_DATE('%D',REGEXP_EXTRACT(event_title,r'\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,4}')) AS event_date
FROM my_table
WHERE PARSE_DATE('%D',REGEXP_EXTRACT(event_title,r'\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,4}')) IS NOT NULL;
```

OR the CTE:

```
WITH events AS
  (
     SELECT
       event_title,
       PARSE_DATE('%D',REGEXP_EXTRACT(event_title,r'\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,4}')) AS event_date
     FROM my_table
  )

SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_date IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Column alias is available after result/output is created, while `WHERE` clause is used for that output creation.

SO, obviously there are many ways to rewrite your query - one way is below

```
SELECT
    event_title,
    PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', REGEXP_EXTRACT(event_title,r'\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,4}')) AS event_date
FROM my_table
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(event_title,r'\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,4}')
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]